# Putting an object on a Request in a Grails Integration Test

Tags: grails, grails-controller

In a Grails project I am looking at here, a filter puts a Domain object on the request...

```
class TokenFilters {

    def filters = {

        all( uri: '/hiphop/**' ) {

            before = {
                MyToken myToken = ...
                request.myToken = myToken
```

MyToken looks like:

```
class MyToken {
    String id
    String token
    static mapping = {
        token( index:  true )
        id( generator: 'uuid' )
    }
    ...
 }
```

In my controller, the myToken is pulled off the request.

```
MyController {
    myaction {
        MyToken accessToken = request.myToken
```

All fine.  I wish to write an integration test for the controller.

```
@Test
void testLogin() {
    def mc = new MyController()    
    def myToken = new MyToken(1234);
    // set the request parameters
    mc.request.parameters = [myToken:myToken];
    def message = mc.action();
    assertTrue(message.indexOf("trans") > 0)

}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Failure:  testLogin(MyTests)
|  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter map value must be single value  or array of type [java.lang.String]
    at testLogin(MyTests.groovy:40)
```

So it looks like Grails will only let me a String or a single value and doesn't like me putting an object on the request in the Filter.  Even thou it lets me put on the same object type in a Filter.

I'd really like to test this without going to Functional tests.  Please help.  I am using Grails 2.2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your code is passing parameters to the controller. Your emulating an HTTP request which can't handle objects.  What you can do is:

```
mc.request.parameters = [myToken: '1234']
```

and then you're controller/filter would pull out the 1234 and look up MyToken.  If you were testing the controller forwarding then you can put objects in the request.  Not the other way around.

I see now that part of the problem is that you're trying to test a controller that is assuming data coming from a filter.

You've omitted some code, but assuming you are extending ControllerUnitTestCase then you have access to a mock request object.  You should be able to simply do:

```
@Test
void testLogin() {
    def mc = new MyController()    
    def myToken = new MyToken(1234);
    // set the request parameters
    request.myToken = myToken
    def message = mc.action();
    assertTrue(message.indexOf("trans") > 0)
}
```

Comment: I have to pass that parameter to the controller for my test to do anything meaningful

Comment: You don't pass objects to controllers.  You look up objects in controllers based on simple values passed in.  If you need to pass an object to your controller for your test to work, you need to rethink your test.

Comment: thanks but the Filter is setting an object on the request passed to the Controller.  I need to simulate the same request.